# Record stream using SDP file & ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a stream created using ffmpeg using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 4 -i video.mp4 -strict -2 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:51372 -sdp_file test.sdp
```

This creates a .sdp file while streaming the local video file over RTP.

The SDP file:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Serenity - HD DVD Trailer
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.29.100
m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:4674
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAKaw05QFAFuhAAZdOwExLQCPGDEWA,aO68sA==; profile-level-id=640029
```

Now I want to use another ffmpeg instance to record this stream and save to a file (assuming its another machine in the network).

I tried the following command but it is giving an error.

```
ffmpeg -i test.sdp -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 60 -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 test.mp4
```

The error:

```
Protocol 'rtp' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
custom.sdp: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding `-protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp`. I am not sure where to position that parameters, but ffmpeg seems to rely on such things.

Greets
Joachim

Answer (score 0):

`-protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp` must be specified *before* the input `-i test.sdp` in your command.